# Can't start dhcpd on Ubuntu with systemd

Tags: networking, dhcp, systemd

I am having a strange problem running `dhcpd` on Ubuntu (x64).  I am using `systemd` to start `dhcpd` on bootup and it just exits.

When I query service status

```
$ systemctl status dhcpd
dhcpd.service - dhcpcd service
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dhcpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2016-08-16 20:37:11 UTC; 15min ago
Process: 1591 ExecStart=/sbin/dhcpd -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf eth1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1591 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

When I look at the journal I don't see any errors either:

```
journalctl _PID=1591

Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.3-P1
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.3-P1
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: All rights reserved.
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: All rights reserved.
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Config file: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Config file: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Database file: /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Database file: /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: PID file: /var/run/dhcpd.pid
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: PID file: /var/run/dhcpd.pid
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Listening on LPF/eth1/08:00:27:10:48:17/192.168.0.0/24
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Listening on LPF/eth1/08:00:27:10:48:17/192.168.0.0/24
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Sending on   LPF/eth1/08:00:27:10:48:17/192.168.0.0/24
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Sending on   LPF/eth1/08:00:27:10:48:17/192.168.0.0/24
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Sending on   Socket/fallback/fallback-net
Aug 16 20:37:11 kirk.sb.computer dhcpd[1591]: Sending on   Socket/fallback/fallback-net
```

It looks like everything is fine, but `dhcpd` is not running.

My configuration file (`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`) is very simple:

```
# dhcp server configuration file

allow bootp;  #allow bootp protocol

#define DHCP subnet
#specify /etc/spock/spock.ub as boot file
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.200;
    filename "/etc/spock/spock.ub";
}
```

In my service script I make sure dhcpd won't start until network is up:

```
# Start and stop dhcpcd service on eth1 interface

[Unit]
Description=dhcpcd service
# Come up after networking
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
#start dhcpd on eth1
ExecStart=/sbin/dhcpd -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf eth1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It also exits when I try to start it via `systemctl start dhcpd`  However, if I execute `'/sbin/dhcpd -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf eth1'` from the command line it works fine.

Any idea why it exits?

Answer (score 1):

dhcpd forks itself so I had to change service type appropriately:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/sbin/dhcpd -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf eth1
```

Now it works

Answer (score 0):

If that script needs to be ran after the network interface is fully functional and able to connect to the outer world as `network-online.target` suggests then you might want to test the connection first by pinging google for example.

I'm suggesting you create a separate script containing ping test prior to your `/sbin/dhcpd -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf eth1` command and then execute that script using `ExecStart` in your service.